# Bash: Store the file date in a variable without printing it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want to store the last modified date of a file in a variable. I tried `fileDate= date -r $file "+%Y-%m-%d"` but the `date` command is printing the date instead of storing it in `$fileDate`. how do I do this?

Comment: Your command sets the variable `fileDate` to an empty string and then executes the `date` command in this environment.

Comment: @user1934428 What do you mean by 'in this environment'. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The environment in which the command runs. If you write a command `A=B C`, this execeutes the command C. `C` inherits the environment from the parent process, but with the slight modification, that the variable `A` in it is set to `B`. Note that you can also set more than one variable when running a child process, i.e. `X=1 Y=2 Z=3 C` runs `C` with the environment enhanced by X, Y and Z.